# undefined method operators on legal Postgresql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm beginner, so sorry if i ask for something trivial.

Two tables **imed_patient** and **imed_operator** are legal Postgresql tables with relation between them (many patients to one operator by r_opr_code field in imed_patient), described by definitions:

```
class ImedOperator < ActiveRecord::Base     
 self.table_name = "imed_operator"  
 self.primary_key = "code"

 belongs_to :ImedPatient 
end 

class ImedPatient < ActiveRecord::Base  
 self.table_name = "imed_patient"   
 self.primary_key = "code"

 has_one :ImedOperator, :foreign_key => "r_opr_code"
end
```

I want to view all patients with data (ex. name, surname) from imed_operator (details of patients), so I produced pacjenci_controller.rb

```
class PacjenciController < ApplicationController
     def index      
       @patients = ImedPatient.all      
       @operator = @patients.operators   
     end

  def show      
    @patient = ImedPatient.find(params[:id])   
  end 
end
```

In web broweser I receive error :

```
NoMethodError in PacjenciController#index
undefined method `operators' for #<ImedPatient::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbb269ffe00>
```

Extracted source (around line #5):      @operator = @patient.operators

UPDATE:

my index.html.erb

```
<h1>Pacjenci w Optimed</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Nazwisko</th>
    <th>Imię</th>
    <th>Pesel</th>
    <th>Code_operator</th>
    <th>Wizyty</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to @operator.surname, controller: "pacjenci", action: "show", id: patient.r_opr_code %></td> 
    <td><%= @operator.first_name %></td> 
    <td><%= @operator.pesel %></td> 
    <td><%= patient.r_opr_code %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Wizyty', url_for(action: 'wizytypacjenta', controller: 'wizyty', id: patient.code) %></td> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br>

<p><%= link_to 'Start', url_for(action: 'index', controller: 'pacjenci') %></p>
<p><%= link_to 'Wstecz', url_for(:back) %></p>
```

And I stucked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, I'm not sure you are doing what you want to do. In the index action you are calling `ImedPatient.all`, so you will get all the records. That's why the variable should be called `@patients`, not `@patient`. Then, if you want to get all operators for all the patients, you should use

```
@operator = @patients.map(&:imed_operator)
```

If you made a mistake and you actually wanted the `@operator` in `show` action it should be:

```
@operator = @patient.imed_operator
```

Update: another problem is the `has_one` declaration. I think it should be:

```
has_one :imed_operator, :foreign_key => "r_opr_code"
```

Update 2:

After what you have written in comments it seems that you have confused the association and it should be the other way:

```
class ImedOperator < ActiveRecord::Base     
 has_one :imed_patient, foreign_key: 'r_opr_code'
end 

class ImedPatient < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :imed_operator , foreign_key: 'r_opr_code'
end
```

Have a look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one

Comment: OK, once again I changed to your proposal : '@operator = @patients.map(&:imed_operator)' and still receive the same error : 'NoMethodError in PacjenciController#index
undefined method `imed_operator' for #<ImedPatient:0x007fbb12e36140> Did you mean? imed_patient imed_patient? imed_patient= build_ImedOperator ImedOperator ImedOperator= Extracted source (around line #5): @operator = @patients.map(&:imed_operator)' Let's forget now about show :)

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PacjenciController#index
PG::UndefinedColumn: BŁĄD: kolumna imed_operator.r_opr_code nie istnieje LINE 1: ...ECT "imed_operator".* FROM "imed_operator" WHERE "imed_oper... ^ : SELECT "imed_operator".* FROM "imed_operator" WHERE "imed_operator"."r_opr_code" = $1 LIMIT 1

Comment: After last change he think that imed_operator have field r_opr_code, and this field exist only in imed_patient (FK key)

Comment: You don't have the `r_opr_code` column. Have you ran proper database migrations? It should exist in the `imed_operators` column.

Comment: This is legal database (not build in Ruby). I want to add new functionality to Optimed program which generate and use this database. I need to operate only in read mode on it. imed_patient.r_opr_code it is FK of imed_operator.code

Comment: OK, it seems that I pass to index.html.erb without errors. How I should now call fields from imed_operator table inside index : for example by  @operator.surname  ????

Comment: @ArtLion Accept the correct answer and create a new question. It starts to be messy here.

Answer (score 1):

ImedPatient has_one ImedOperator, so you need to change

`@operator = @patient.operators`

to 

`@operator = @patient.imed_operator`

Comment: Also its not `operator`, it is `imed_operator`.

Comment: @Pavan Thanks for catch.

Comment: I changed to @operator = @patient.imed_operator and still have problem undefined method `imed_operator' for # ImedPatient::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbb1042ff90> in line @operator = @patient.imed_operator. So nothing change :(

Comment: Do you have r_opr_code_id defined in imed_operators table?And what's the reason for seting self.table_name and self.primary_key?

Comment: @ArtLion It looks from your code that imed_patient table have r_opr_code column,  but imed_operator table should have that columns since they belongs_to ImedPatient.

Comment: This is legal Postgresql database (not build in Ruby). I want to add new functionality to program which generate and use this database. I need to operate only in read mode on it. imed_patient.r_opr_code it is FK of imed_operator.code. I can't add fields and don't want to do this. This is just simple relation between tables and not the same name of fields.

Comment: If r_opr_code is the FK on imed_operator then I think that you should do as @pmichna said in Update 2.